# In Intellij IDEA, how do I edit the Alt-Enter options?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA, I use the Alt-Enter intention actions a lot. One thing that I do a lot is to use them to initialise local variables.

However, when I'm initialising a local variable of an object that is an `Enum`, the first intention action that Intellij IDEA offers is to 'create enum constant' - for example:

[image]

This seems like an odd choice as a intention shortcut, especially as the first option - generally, I think of `Enum` as representing things that shouldn't often be changed. (Indeed, having it as the first option causes me all sorts of headaches. My muscle memory is that Alt-Enter, Enter will initialise the local variable - but not if it's an `Enum`! Then I have to unpick the changes it's put in, which gets tedious after a while...)

In any case, I'd like to disable this as an intention shortcut from the Alt-Enter popups. However, despite having trawled through the Intellij settings, I haven't been able to work out how to change this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of IDEA are you using? I use 2016.2.4 and I already get the behaviour that you are asking for ...

[image]

Comment: I was using 15.0.6 - I had delayed upgrading to 2016.x due to the Java 8 requirements, but everything seems fine with 2016.2.5, and I confirm that they have changed this quick-fix to the behaviour I would want/expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to turn off individual quickfixes for an inspection or a compilation error. What you can do is file a YouTrack issue showing your code example with a bit more context and explaining why you think the quickfix is not appropriate, and the IntelliJ IDEA development team can then consider disabling it in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could find setting as: **Ctrl+Alt+S** then **Editor/Intentions**